# Spring Boot JPA bootstrapping the database

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When using Spring Boot JPA (Hibernate), what is the best way to bootstrap the database with some seed data (MySQL in this case)? For example in Grails you can use the `bootstrap.groovy` file to accomplish this. I couldn't feel out a real consensus out there on what the best way to go about this is as in best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Liquibase` or `Flyway` approach.

Or the following `Spring Boot` properties:

`spring.datasource.data= # Data (DML) script resource references.`

`spring.datasource.schema= # Schema (DDL) script resource references.`

Another solution would be to create your own `Bootstrap` bean and run it before app started, see how the Spring Boot runs `Flyway` or `Liquibase` as a reference.

[Database initialization documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a file in `resources` folder, named it `schema.sql` and put your MySQL DB script in there. When your application start, `schema.sql` will be loaded automatically